# Remove the + sign from bundled product prices

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, bundled-product, product-view

How can I remove the leading **'+' sign** from prices of **bundled product** components? I have tried changing the `$sign = ''; // Originally was $sign = '+';` and also `$priceStr = ''; // Originally was $priceStr = $sign;` in `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Abstract.php`, without luck.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The responsible code is in `Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option`:

[`getSelectionQtyTitlePrice()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option.php#L193)

```
    $priceTitle .= ' &nbsp; ' . ($includeContainer ? '<span class="price-notice">' : '')
        . '+' . $this->formatPriceString($price, $includeContainer)
        . ($includeContainer ? '</span>' : '');
```

and [`getSelectionTitlePrice()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option.php#L231)

```
    $priceTitle .= ' &nbsp; ' . ($includeContainer ? '<span class="price-notice">' : '')
        . '+' . $this->formatPriceString($price, $includeContainer)
        . ($includeContainer ? '</span>' : '');
```

You can extend the class, override these methods and remove the plus sign. Then you need to rewrite [all its child classes](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option):

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <bundle>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option>Your_Module_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option>
                    <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox>Your_Module_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Checkbox</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox>
                    <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_multi>Your_Module_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Multi</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_multi>
                    <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio>Your_Module_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Radio</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio>
                    <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select>Your_Module_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Select</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select>
                </rewrite>
            </bundle>
    ...
```

These rewritten classes are copies of their originals (there is not much individual code, just the templates being defined) and must extend your class from above instead of the original `Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option`

Comment: thank your for the reply.  That does the job.  My question is, If by changing `'+'` to `' '`, you solve the problem, why would you extend the class? And excuse my ignorance, what is extending the class?

Comment: Of course, I have created an override of `Option.php` and applied the changes mentioned above in `getSelectionQtyTitlePrice()` and `getSelectionTitlePrice()` here: `app/code/local/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option.php`.

Comment: I always prefer a solution without changing core code or overriding it in the local code pool. With a custom module and class rewrites you only need to change the methods that you need to change which is easier to understand and more upgrade safe.

Comment: But I figured that if you prefer quick and easy code pool overrides, my answer would provide you with everything you need. Looks like I was right ;)